# Memory leak from a bat script

Tags: windows, winforms, memory, handler, break

I created a bat script that takes the output of one program and searches it in the default browser by opening up a URL.
Ive noticed that by the end of the day, a Im getting a critical error with Windows Handlers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghZAf.png)

After doing some research I believe its caused by voulume of requests sent to the Batch script, resulting in it hitting Windows Handler 10k limit

If anyone have any recommendations or suggestions let me know because I was not able to find a clear solution for this memory leak. Here is the batch script:

```
echo off
set str=%1
rem echo.%str%
set str=%str:-=%
rem echo.%str%
start chrome.exe "https://averdi.sugarondemand.com/#search/%str%"
```

Im trying to find a piece of code that might clear the used resources each time the bat script runs but im not having much luck in finding. or anything that will stop this memory leak. Appraicte all help

Comment: The only memory being used here is by opening Chrome, and that has nothing to do with a batch file. If you're opening many instances of Chrome without closing them, you're eating up all the memory. Since Chrome is for presenting a user interface, you're probably doing something totally wrong and it's causing an XY problem, but we don't know what X is to try and help you fix it.

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down,  my goal was to take the output of a program and paste it into a URL to open a webpage in a default browser.  I tried making a similar program in C++ and as mentioned in the batch script both got the same exact error. If there is a more consistent method for this, Im all ears.  In my instance, the browser gets manually closed after the output is displayed

Comment: I just looked at the image you posted, and the problem is not a memory leak. It's a **handle** leak, which is caused by opening too many GUI objects (such as windows) and not releasing them properly, and is related to WinForms. Since Chrome does not use WinForms, and nothing in the batch file you've posted has anything to do with WinForms, the error has nothing to do with the batch file at all. I'd guess the problem is related to the *one program* you mention, or the *similar program in C++*, neither of which has anything to do with the batch file or Chrome.

Comment: That makes sense, so the program that outputs a value into the batch script is from a 3rd party vendor whose software outputs an incoming call's phone number.  I tried writing a C++ and this batch script to just take that input and open a URL in a browser but both result in the same Critical error after day's worth of use.   I wasn't able to find a way to code a Windows break handler reset or clear through a batch script, so its going to be a challenge to convince the 3rd party vendor that their software is causing the crash since its only passes the information along to our script.

Comment: Then point the 3rd party vendor to this post. We can't help with that app, as you don't have the source code, and we are not support for third-party apps of any kind. The batch file is NOT causing the issue, and neither is Chrome - neither of them can cause a Winforms-related handle leak.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation and dealing with the vendor is my headache to deal with. Appreciate the help!